# how delete one page from pdf by imagemagick

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

i m Wana Delete One page from **PDF** By **imagemagick** , How can this be done? this my code this return just one page in pdf ? what the problem ?

```
 $image = new \Imagick(__DIR__.'/test.pdf');
    $pageNumber = $image->count();
    $page = true;
    $imgs = [];
    for($i=0 ; $i<$pageNumber ; $i++){

        $image->readImage(__DIR__.'/test.pdf['.$i.']');

        if($i === 2 && $page == true){
            $image->removeImage();
            $page = false;
            continue;
        }

        // $imgs[] = __DIR__.'images'.$i.'.jpg';
    }
    $image->setImageFormat("pdf");
    $image->writeImage('images.pdf');
   file_put_contents(__DIR__.'images'.$i.'.pdf',$image);
```

Comment: make for me 7 pdf file in the loop !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the original pdf is having 5 pages (known as fivepage.pdf), then you may use the following steps to remove page 3 from it and generate a new pdf known as combined.pdf

1. use Imagick to open the pdf
2. determine the number of pages
3. loop over each page of this pdf
4. save the pages into separate , temporary jpeg files
5. push the jpeg files (except page 3, $i==2) into array
6. use the array to generate the "combined.pdf"
7. delete all the temp jpeg files

So the code is:

```
<?php

$file="./fivepage.pdf";
$im = new Imagick($file);
$resultimages = array();
$noOfPagesInPDF = $im->getNumberImages(); 
 
        // loop over all the pdf pages

          for ($i = 0; $i < $noOfPagesInPDF; $i++) { 
              $url = $file.'['.$i.']'; 
              $image = new Imagick();
        
        //      $image->setResolution(300,300);
        // use the above line if you want higher resolution
              
              $image->readimage($url);
              $image->setImageFormat("jpg"); 
          
              $image->writeImage("./temp_".($i+1).'.jpg'); 

        // include all pages except page 3 ($i==2)
              if ($i!=2) {
              array_push($resultimages, "./temp_".($i+1).'.jpg');
              }

          } 

       // generate the resulting pdf (omitting page 3)
      $pdf = new Imagick($resultimages);
      $pdf->setImageFormat('pdf');
      $pdf->writeImages('combined.pdf', true); 

      // clear temp images
             for ($i = 0; $i < $noOfPagesInPDF; $i++) { 
             unlink("./temp_".($i+1).'.jpg'); 
             }


    echo "pdf without page 3 saved";


   ?>
```